# How to access more storage from Ubuntu USB

Tags: usb

I downloaded Ubuntu USB onto my USB drive and ran it as my operating system, but when I try to download something to Ubuntu it says I do not have enough disk space.

Comment: What are you doing? Running a live ubuntu or???

Comment: Do you ran Ubuntu as live or installed Ubuntu by Wine?

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop or "Live" runs on a read only file system and has limited space. You can not save your settings between booting and you will have limited space for saving your work.

You can, however, save data to your hard drive or a second flash drive.

You can also condifure your usb drive. You can add a second partition or boot the live CD with persistance.

Depending on what you are wanting and the size of your flash drive, perhaps you can simply install Ubuntu onto the usb drive.